# How do I expand variables in a bash variable without expanding wildcard?

Tags: bash, eval

I have a variable that contains this kind of string :

```
var='$FOO/bar/baz*'
```

and I want to replace the variable $FOO by its content. However, when i do

```
var=$(eval "echo $var")
```

The variable is replaced, but the star is also replaced so that `var` now contains every possible match in my filesystem (as if i pressed tab in a shell).
for example, if $FOO contains /home, `var` will contain `"/home/bar/baz1.sh /home/bar/baz2.sh /home/bar/baz.conf"`

How do i replace the variable without expanding wildcards ?

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles

Comment: If your goal is to disable only globbing, `set -f` will do that. If your goal is to do safe template evaluation... well, nothing is _safe_ about templates in bash, since you can't disable command substitution; that is, a template containing `$(rm -rf "$HOME")` will do just that.

Answer (score 10):

Turn off globbing in bash, then reenable it.

```
set -f 
var="$FOO/bar/baz*"
set +f
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the quotes:

```
var=$FOO/bar/baz/*
```

Globs are not expanded on the RHS of a variable assignment.

Comment: I cringe as I suggest it, but how about: `var='$FOO/bar/baz*'; eval "expandedvar=$var"` (warning: `eval` opens the door for so many ways for things to go wrong it's not even funny).

Comment: I not sure why `eval` is necessary at all. In my answer, `var`'s value will be "whateverwasinfoo/bar/baz/*". The variable `$FOO` is expanded, the star is not. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: My understanding was that he already has a variable set to `$FOO/bar/baz*` (or something similar), not that the script will contain that string directly.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the problem. The string contained in my variable is actually read from a file. That's why u can't change anything about how the value is set. I have to change it after (with eval for example, but with the problem i mentionned)

Comment: Not only does this answer not help (because the variable is already set as Godon and Kaidjin mentioned) but it is also just plain wrong.  Globs ARE expanded on the RHS of variable assignment. (at least as of bash 3.2) Example: `var=test.*; echo $var` result: `test.make test.sh test.txt` etc.

Comment: The glob expansion does not occur until `$var` is expanded. Try `echo "$var"`.

Comment: As Charles Duffy pointed out 3 years ago, there is no safe way to do what the OP wants.